# Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I created a macro for a file and first it was working fine, but today I've been opening and restarting the file and macro hundreds of times and I'm always getting the following error:

> Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

I didn't change anything in the macro and don't know why am I getting the error. Furthermore it takes ages to update the macro every time I put it running (the macro has to run about 9000 rows).

The error is on the line in the between ** **.

VBA:

```
Sub k()

Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, a As Integer
Dim name As String
name = InputBox("Please insert the name of the sheet")
i = 1
Sheets(name).Cells(4, 58) = Sheets(name).Cells(4, 57)
x = Sheets(name).Cells(4, 57).Value
Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets(name).Cells(i + 4, 57))
    a = 0
    If Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) <> x Then
        If Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) <> 0 Then
            If Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) = 3 Then
                a = x
                Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 58) = Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) - x
                x = Cells(4 + i, 57) - x
            End If
            **Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 58) = Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) - a**
            x = Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) - a
        Else
        Cells(4 + i, 58) = ""
        End If
    Else
    Cells(4 + i, 58) = ""
    End If

i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I'm using excel 2010 on windows 7.

Comment: Probably you are doing an if statement and comparing a string and not using double quotes. Use `="3"` not `= 3`

Answer (score 10):

You would get a type mismatch if `Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57)` contains a non-numeric value. You should validate the fields before you assume they are numbers and try to subtract from them.

<s>Also, you should enable `Option Strict` so you are forced to explicitly convert your variables before trying to perform type-dependent operations on them such as subtraction. That will help you identify and eliminate issues in the future, too.</s>
   Unfortunately `Option Strict` is for VB.NET only. Still, you should look up best practices for explicit data type conversions in VBA.

---

**Update:**

If you are trying to go for the quick fix of your code, however, wrap the `**` line and the one following it in the following condition:

```
If IsNumeric(Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57))
    Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 58) = Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) - a
    x = Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) - a
End If
```

Note that your `x` value may not contain its expected value in the next iteration, however.

Comment: It's allways numeric values between 0 and 3.

Comment: I got the error in the first line of the code you gave me "Compile error: Syntax error"

Comment: There shouldn't be any syntax error. Make sure you put it right after your other `If` statement and that you have all the parentheses.

Comment: `Option Strict` is VB.NET, not VBA.

Comment: Option Strict is not available in VBA for Excel, however, you can chose between these 4: 

Base, Compare, Explicit and Private.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you guys for all your help! Finally I was able to make it work perfectly thanks to a friend and also you!
Here is the final code so you can also see how we solve it.

Thanks again!

```
Option Explicit

Sub k()

Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, a As Integer
Dim name As String
'name = InputBox("Please insert the name of the sheet")
i = 1
name = "Reserva"
Sheets(name).Cells(4, 57) = Sheets(name).Cells(4, 56)

On Error GoTo fim
x = Sheets(name).Cells(4, 56).Value
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets(name).Cells(i + 4, 56))
    a = 0
    If Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 56) <> x Then
        If Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 56) <> 0 Then
            If Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 56) = 3 Then
                a = x
                Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) = Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 56) - x
                x = Cells(4 + i, 56) - x
            End If
            Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 57) = Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 56) - a
            x = Sheets(name).Cells(4 + i, 56) - a
        Else
        Cells(4 + i, 57) = ""
        End If
    Else
    Cells(4 + i, 57) = ""
    End If

i = i + 1
Loop
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Exit Sub
fim:
MsgBox Err.Description
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: you provided a solution but you didn't explain what changed...

Answer (score 1):

Diogo

Justin has given you some very fine tips :)

You will also get that error if the cell where you are performing the calculation has an error resulting from a formula.

For example if Cell A1 has #DIV/0! error then you will get "Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch" when performing this code

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value - 1
```

I have made some slight changes to your code. Could you please test it for me? Copy the code with the line numbers as I have deliberately put them there.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, a As Integer, y As Integer
  Dim name As String
  Dim lastRow As Long
10        On Error GoTo Whoa

20        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

30        name = InputBox("Please insert the name of the sheet")

40        If Len(Trim(name)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

50        Set ws = Sheets(name)

60        With ws
70            If Not IsError(.Range("BE4").Value) Then
80                x = Val(.Range("BE4").Value)
90            Else
100               MsgBox "Please check the value of cell BE4. It seems to have an error"
110               GoTo LetsContinue
120           End If

130           .Range("BF4").Value = x

140           lastRow = .Range("BE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

150           For i = 5 To lastRow
160               If IsError(.Range("BE" & i)) Then
170                   MsgBox "Please check the value of cell BE" & i & ". It seems to have an error"
180                   GoTo LetsContinue
190               End If

200               a = 0: y = Val(.Range("BE" & i))
210               If y <> x Then
220                   If y <> 0 Then
230                       If y = 3 Then
240                           a = x
250                           .Range("BF" & i) = Val(.Range("BE" & i)) - x

260                           x = Val(.Range("BE" & i)) - x
270                       End If
280                       .Range("BF" & i) = Val(.Range("BE" & i)) - a
290                       x = Val(.Range("BE" & i)) - a
300                   Else
310                       .Range("BF" & i).ClearContents
320                   End If
330               Else
340                   .Range("BF" & i).ClearContents
350               End If
360           Next i
370       End With

LetsContinue:
380       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
390       Exit Sub
Whoa:
400       MsgBox "Error Description :" & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
         "Error at line     : " & Erl
410       Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: I got the error "Compile error: Variable not define" in the line 130 "lastrow="

Comment: No errors but my excel sheet is freezing everytime I try it :(

Comment: Since there are 9000 rows, give it sometime. Wait and see what happens. Alternatively if you want change LINE 20 to True instead of False. Application.ScreenUpdating = True and then check it. Does it shown any sign of being alive?

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:

This function was abending in `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`

```
Function fnIsNumber(Value) As Boolean
  fnIsNumber = Evaluate("ISNUMBER(0+""" & Value & """)")
End Function
```

In my case, the function was failing when it ran into a `#DIV/0!` or `N/A` value.

To solve it, I had to do this:

```
Function fnIsNumber(Value) As Boolean
   If CStr(Value) = "Error 2007" Then '<===== This is the important line
      fnIsNumber = False
   Else
      fnIsNumber = Evaluate("ISNUMBER(0+""" & Value & """)")
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you mentioned here above and my code was doing great all day yesterday.

I kept on programming this morning and when I opened my application (my file with an Auto_Open sub), I got the Run-time error '13' Type mismatch, I went on the web to find answers, I tried a lot of things, modifications and at one point I remembered that I read somewhere about "Ghost" data that stays in a cell even if we don't see it.

My code do only data transfer from one file I opened previously to another and Sum it. My code stopped at the third SheetTab (So it went right for the 2 previous SheetTab where the same code went without stopping) with the Type mismatch message. And it does that every time at the same SheetTab when I restart my code.

So I selected the cell where it stopped, manually entered 0,00 (Because the Type mismatch comes from a Summation variables declared in a DIM as Double) and copied that cell in all the subsequent cells where the same problem occurred. It solved the problem. Never had the message again. Nothing to do with my code but the "Ghost" or data from the past. It is like when you want to use the Control+End and Excel takes you where you had data once and deleted it. Had to "Save" and close the file when you wanted to use the Control+End to make sure Excel pointed you to the right cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub HighlightSpecificValue()

'PURPOSE: Highlight all cells containing a specified values


Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

'What value do you want to find?
  fnd = InputBox("I want to hightlight cells containing...", "Highlight")

    'End Macro if Cancel Button is Clicked or no Text is Entered
      If fnd = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)

enter code here
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

'Test to see if anything was found
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFound = FoundCell.Address

  Else
    GoTo NothingFound
  End If

Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    'Find next cell with fnd value
      Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)







    'Add found cell to rng range variable
      Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)

    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
      If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do


  Loop

'Highlight Found cells yellow

  rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

  Dim fnd1 As String
  fnd1 = "Rah"
  'Condition highlighting

  Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)



  If FoundCell.Value("rah") Then
      rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

  ElseIf FoundCell.Value("Nav") Then

    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)



    End If





'Report Out Message
  MsgBox rng.Cells.Count & " cell(s) were found containing: " & fnd

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
  MsgBox "No cells containing: " & fnd & " were found in this worksheet"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the input variable type is wrong. You probably have written a formula in `Cells(4 + i, 57)` that instead of `=0`, the formula `= ""` have used. So when running this error is displayed. Because empty string is not equal to zero.

[image]