# Error 13 with Dropdown list Audit Log

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do an audit log for a report.  One of the things the report is a status section which can be selected through a drop down list.  Here is my code.

```
Option Explicit
Dim PreviousValue As Variant  



Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("E" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
        If Range("D2").Value = "I/C" Then
        Range("E" & Target.Row).Locked = True
        Range("E" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
        Else
        Range("E" & Target.Row).Locked = False
        End If

    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3")) Is Nothing Then
         Range("E" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("E" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then
         Range("E" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If

    Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
    Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Equipment"
    Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Old Status"
    Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(1, 4).Value = "New Status"
    Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Old Reason"
    Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(1, 6).Value = "New Reason"
    Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(1, 7).Value = "Old Action"
    Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(1, 8).Value = "New Action"

    If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
   Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Now
   Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(65000, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, -1)
   Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(65000, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Cells(Target.Row, 1)
   Sheets("GC-01 History Log").Cells(65000, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Value

End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
PreviousValue = Target.Value

End Sub
```

The problem is that when I try to change the status through the drop down menu.  An Error 13 gets thrown.  I have no idea on how to deal with this.

EDIT:-  On the debug it shows that the error is If "Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then"

Please Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885506/excel-vba-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch)

Comment: I read the link but I still don't understand how to fix it myself.

Comment: The error 13 means they are of different types.  It could be caused by `PreviousValue` being `Nothing`, so you should validate for that

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First: This

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

only works if you actually *change* your selection. So this might cause `PreviousValue` to be empty.

Second and more important:

You want to declare `PreviousValue` as `Public`, else you cannot use it in both subroutines.

```
Option Explicit
Public PreviousValue As Variant
...
```

is what you want.

Comment: How do you suggest to improve that so the change catches?