# Excel Macro Hide Columns Based on String

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro in Excel 2016 that auto hides columns based on a string contained in a different cell.  Right now, the Range R1:GJU1 is a formula that populates an X with an IF formula.

This is my code:

```
Sub Hide_Columns_Containing_Value()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("R1:GJU1").Cells
        If c.Value = "X" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

I get this error:

```
Run-time error '13':

Type mismatch
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885506/excel-vba-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch) may be of some help to you

Comment: try `Columns(c.column).EntireColumn.Hidden = False`.  ...assuming the error is on that line.

Comment: I tried using your code for that line and am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am typing this from my phone so I can not test it, but doing this:

```
Columns(c.column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

will work.  Basically, what you are trying to do is just say `Cell.Hide` which will not work.  The `EntireColumn.Hidden` will work when referencing a column.   So, you should say, hide the `column` of this `cells' column`.

I also noticed you are setting it to `False` which means, *Unhide*.  I am guessing that was done erroneously, unless you are in fact trying to Unhide it.

The full code should be:

```
Sub Hide_Columns_Containing_Value()

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("R1:GJU1").Cells
    If c.Value = "X" Then
        Columns(c.column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for weighing in.  So my worksheet has Columns hidden for the user initially.  I have a drop down (using a Data Validation range) that changes R1:GJU1 to an 'X' with an IF statement (mostly because I could not get the macro to work with my drop down).

When I use your code, it does work!  Now, what if I wanted the user to be able to select different options on the drop down to 're-hide' the prior columns (on the old criteria per drop down) and only show the new columns?

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense!  Did the code help at all or no?

Comment: Sorry, edited my prior comment.  The code did help, now trying to optimize to make it more dynamic to only display a value in the particular cell.

Comment: So you can tap into the drop down list itself and call a macro for when it's changed. If changed to a certain value then `do stuff`. But, that question is drastically different than this. For the sake of the usefulness of the site, you should ask that as a new question as they are quite different from one another. If my answer was correct do me a favor and Mark it as the right answer. :) Post the new question and once it's posted I'll help on that one too!