# Run-time error 13 in my VBA code when generating batch number

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble with the datatype in my code. I converted the 6 to a string but I'm getting the same error. Any suggestions please?

```
Sub test1()
' Generates batch number based on company code

Dim x As Integer
Dim a As Integer    

a = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row    

For x = 6 To a    
    If Cells(x, 2).Value = "US1K" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Value = 1

    ElseIf Cells(x, 2).Value = "USYB" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Value = 2

    ElseIf Cells(x, 2).Value = "US1A" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Value = 3

    ElseIf Cells(x, 2).Value = "US4U" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Value = 4

    ElseIf Cells(x, 2).Value = "US3D" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Value = 5
 Else
        Cells(x, 1).Value = " "

    End If
   Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885506/excel-vba-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch)

Comment: @Capricorn - it is a bit similar, but far away from a duplicate. The OP is writing to a cell, which can values which are non-numeric as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably one of the cells is with an error. Try only this part and see whether you get a `MsgBox()`. Then, incorporate the `IsError()` part in your code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim a As Long

    a = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 6 To a
        If IsError(Cells(x, 2)) Then
            MsgBox Cells(x, 2).Address
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'do the rest of your code here
    Next x

End Sub
```

- [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

Comment: You keep beating me to it by a couple of seconds - was going to mention the `Integer` to `Long` problem and then add a comment here about a cell containing an error.... ah well, never mind. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - still can mention the complete referring to `Worksheet()` problem :D

Comment: Looking for someone to mention error handler and the "bad smell" from the `Exit Sub` in the middle. :D

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time coding for work. I appreciate the help! y'all are awesome

Comment: @jojo - you are welcome! :) Consider marking this answer as an accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yes of course! By the way, why did I need to change it to Long?

Comment: @jojo - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long

Comment: @jojo - consider putting your code here  - https://codereview.stackexchange.com, you may get some useful ideas.

Comment: I'll take a look. I appreciate all the help:D