# clear dependent dropdown list in excel sheet for multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I am having excel sheet . which is having the field for country and state field 
when I am changing the country value from united state to canada the state field should be cleared . 
I have done this using below code for single row But I am not able to do it for multiple rows with same format could you please guide me for the same

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
Cells(3, 26).Value = "Please select"
End If

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row > 2 and Target.Row < 10 Then
   If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 then
      ' User just changed the country
      Target.Offset(0,-1).Value = "Please select"
      Target.Offset(0,-2).Value = ""
      Target.Offset(0,-3).Value = ""
   End If
End If

End Sub
```

Enter you own values for Min and Max Rows (in place of the 2 and 10 I used)

Comment: Great, be grateful if you would upvote/mark it as solved

Comment: When i  copy paste the value I am getting error message that type mismatch error 13 . Could you please help me how can i resolve it

Comment: Copy & Paste what value ? can you explain a bit more - which line of code is it crashing on ?  This error arises when data type clash (eg adding a lettter to a number or similar

Comment: I am getting this error. When i am copying entire row no 2 to row no 3.

Comment: May i know  do we need to add the below stmt Application.EnableEvents = False

Comment: You do not NEED to alter the EnableEvents property. Whether you wish to suppress all events within any block of code is a matter for the developer to decide for each particular situation. In this code the cells being changed are not in column 4, if they were I would definitely suppress event firing before making the changes

Comment: Ok I got it .randomly when i am copying the value from one row to another row  I am getting the run time error 13. May i know is there anyway to handle it

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885506/excel-vba-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch

Comment: I have just made one amendment  ... by adding to line 4 of the answer with ...  And Target.Cells.Count = 1   ensuring only 1 cell selected not a range beginning in column 4

Comment: Hi, Could you please help me with the error code . will it be resolved  if i use  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then

Comment: The code "If Target.Column = 4" provides the same protection you do not need  Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) and since you do not have a Rng variable in my answer that will cause you problems anyway. Nothing in the above answer is going to cause your error. That is a different problem. I suggest you post that as a different question and provide a sample set of data and show what you were copying where and then we can address that

Comment: Post a comment back here with a link to your new question if you wish so we'll be able to follow it up easily

Comment: Thank you so much for your timely reply. I will close this as completed and i will raise as a new question

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below instead of what you have.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const FirstDataRow As Long = 2          ' modify as appropriate
    Const CtryClm As String = "E"           ' modify as appropriate
    Const StateClm As String = "D"          ' modify as appropriate

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Msg As String

    Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstDataRow, CtryClm), _
                    Cells(Rows.Count, CtryClm).End(xlUp))
    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
                If Len(.Value) Then Msg = "Please select"
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(.Row, StateClm).Value = Msg
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The code will respond to a change in any single cell (not when you paste multiple cells at once) and enter "Please select" only if the entry in the CountryColumn isn't "".